# Refactoring to eliminate global variable in recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

### In Summary

I am creating a tree structure out of a text file input using a function from SO question: [Python file parsing: Build tree from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6076821/1290420). But I am able to produce my tree only by using a global variable and cannot find a way of avoiding this.

### Input Data

In a file called `data.txt` I have the following:

```
Root
-A 10
-B
--B A 2
--B B 5
--B Z 9
--B X
---X 4
---Y
----Y0 67
----Y1 32
---Z 3
-C 19
```

### Desired Result

```
{'B': ['B A 2', 'B B 5', 'B Z 9', 'B X'],
 'B X': ['X 4', 'Y', 'Z 3'],
 'Root': ['A 10', 'B', 'C 19'],
 'Y': ['Y0 67', 'Y1 32']}
```

### My Code

```
import re, pprint
PATTERN = re.compile('^[-]+')
tree = {}

def _recurse_tree(parent, depth, source):
    last_line = source.readline().rstrip()
    while last_line:
        if last_line.startswith('-'):
            tabs = len( re.match(PATTERN, last_line).group() )
        else:
            tabs = 0
        if tabs < depth:
            break
        node = re.sub(PATTERN, '', last_line.strip())
        if tabs >= depth:
            if parent is not None:
                print "%s: %s" %(parent, node)
                if parent in tree:
                    tree[parent].append(node)
                else:
                    tree[parent] = [ node, ]
            last_line = _recurse_tree(node, tabs+1, source)
    return last_line

def main():
    inFile = open("data.txt")
    _recurse_tree(None, 0, inFile)
    pprint.pprint(tree)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### The Problem

How do I get rid of the global variable `tree`? Everything I do seems to make the code much longer or uglier but I would like to use the function heavily and I hate depending on side-effects for the core result.

### Supplement

After the answers below, I revised the code to return the `tree` in the following way. Is this pythonic? Returning a tuple and then tossing the first element seems inelegant.

```
def _recurse_tree(parent, depth, source, tree=None):
    if tree is None:
        tree = {}
    last_line = source.readline().rstrip()
    while last_line:
        if last_line.startswith('-'):
            tabs = len( re.match(PATTERN, last_line).group() )
        else:
            tabs = 0
        if tabs < depth:
            break
        node = re.sub(PATTERN, '', last_line.strip())
        if tabs >= depth:
            if parent is not None:
                print "%s: %s" %(parent, node)
                if parent in tree:
                    tree[parent].append(node)
                else:
                    tree[parent] = [ node, ]
            last_line, tree = _recurse_tree(node, tabs+1, source, tree)
    return last_line, tree

def main():
    inFile = open("data.txt")
    tmp, tree = _recurse_tree(None, 0, inFile)
    pprint.pprint(tree)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `tree` variable is already a mutable; just pass it along with your recursive calls:

```
def _recurse_tree(parent, depth, source, tree=None):
    if tree is None:
        tree = {}

    last_line = source.readline().rstrip()
    while last_line:
        if last_line.startswith('-'):
            tabs = len( re.match(PATTERN, last_line).group() )
        else:
            tabs = 0
        if tabs < depth:
            break
        node = re.sub(PATTERN, '', last_line.strip())
        if tabs >= depth:
            if parent is not None:
                print "%s: %s" %(parent, node)
                if parent in tree:
                    tree[parent].append(node)
                else:
                    tree[parent] = [ node, ]
            last_line = _recurse_tree(node, tabs+1, source, tree)
    return last_line
```

Alternatively, you can use a class to hold the state, it'll be easier to then pluck the state from the instance:

```
class TreeBuilder(object):
    _PATTERN = re.compile('^[-]+')

    def __init__(self, source):
        self.tree = {}
        self.source = source
        self._recurse_tree()

    def _recurse_tree(self, parent=None, depth=0):
         last_line = self.source.readline().rstrip()
         while last_line:
             if last_line.startswith('-'):
                 tabs = len( self._PATTERN.match(last_line).group() )
             else:
                 tabs = 0
             if tabs < depth:
                 break
             node = self._PATTERN.sub('', last_line.strip())
             if tabs >= depth:
                 if parent is not None:
                     print "%s: %s" %(parent, node)
                     if parent in self.tree:
                         self.tree[parent].append(node)
                     else:
                         self.tree[parent] = [ node, ]
                 last_line = self._recurse_tree(node, tabs+1)
         return last_line
```

Then use this like this:

```
def main():
    inFile = open("data.txt")
    builder = TreeBuilder(inFile)
    pprint.pprint(builder.tree)
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn -- I am accepting this solution. Can I get a comment on my supplementary question? I am seeking an elegant way of retrieving the `tree` once it is created and the recursion is finished.

Comment: @gauden: we usually try to keep it to *one* question per post. I'd say it's fine in this case to toss one of the return values of your recursive function, yes. Alternatively, use a class to hold the state instead and then at the end just retrieve the built tree from the class instance you used.

Comment: Thanks @martijn-pieters. I've been around SO long enough to know the rules, so apologies for overstepping this time.

Comment: @gauden: your in luck; I've given you a class-based version anyway, which makes it more pythonic and gives you the tree as an easy-to-reach attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I think good solution here — create class and put tree inside, like a private class member.

Or you can simply pass this dictionary as one of the parameters in function and pass it during recursion. It'll pass by reference, so all time function will use the same dictionary without global variable. But I'd prefer class.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tree` as default parameter in your function: -

```
def _recurse_tree(parent, depth, source, tree = None):
    if tree is None:  # needed on first invocation
        tree = {}
```

Call it first time without `tree` parameter, and on every successive call, add another parameter `tree` to it.

So, from inside your method your recursive call becomes: -

```
last_line = _recurse_tree(node, tabs+1, source, tree)
```

Comment: Ah, I think that giving the advice to use a mutable as the default is the problem here, perhaps? :-) Surely you are familiar with ["Least Astonishment" in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941)?

Comment: @MartijnPieters.. But, that's what is needed. Why would it matter here. `tree` is getting changed on successive call. Still can't understand why the downvote. :(

Comment: @MartijnPieters.. Yeah, that thing I know. But that would matter if we invoke that method multiple times from outside recursion. In recursion, would it matter? I think it should not.

Comment: You can now use this function (from `main()`) only *once*. Next time you call it it'll have the data from the last call still there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters.. Yeah that can be a problem, which I understand. I think I would change it to `None`.

Comment: Yep, define this `def a(tree = {}):tree[len(tree)] = 1;return tree;`, and then call `a()` multiple times.