# Creating a tree in Python

Tags: python

I have a string of tab-indented lines that looks like this:

```
Node A
    Node B
    Node C
        Node D
    Node E
Node F
```

And I hope to get a data structure where I can traverse the tree by the following:

```
print data[Node A][Node B][Node C] => Gives me all children under Node C
```

How can I do this with Python? I don't know what to search for this! Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: Have you tried anything? It's a good idea to at least post an attempt.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python file parsing: Build tree from text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075974/python-file-parsing-build-tree-from-text-file)

Comment: Yes I have been looking/trying at things online for sometime.. It is a bit discouraging to not get any help or a push in the right direction,

Answer (score 3):

You should look at [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/). It is a great library for graph / tree Data Structures.

And for your question on how to parse the tab separated data into a tree structure check [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075974/python-file-parsing-build-tree-from-text-file) to help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

As a start, nested dictionaries could do the job:

```
tree = {
    "a": 5,
    "b": {
        "c": 6
    }
}

node = tree["b"]["c"]
```

Comment: I think he actually wants to know how to convert his tab-indented plain text file to a python dictionary.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought it was just an example of the data in the tree.